# Define function not showing errors but does not return anything when function is run

Tags: python, pandas

I have defined a function the results of which should be output as a dataframe. However when I run the function, the code is not being carried out and the variables created within the function are not being defined (i.e. no results but no errors either). I'm guessing I may be incorrectly using the define function?

This is my defined function:

```
def results(Water_depth,e,intv,Top_res,Base_res,Res_thickness,Depletion, Biot,Cm,C,nu): 
    df_results = pd.DataFrame((np.arange(Water_depth,e,intv)), columns=['Depth'])   # Creating data frame for results
    df_results['Z (m)'] = ((df_results['Depth']) - Water_depth)/Top_res    # Creating normalised depth
    conditions = [
        (df_results['Depth'] < Top_res),
        (df_results['Depth'] >= Top_res) & (df_results['Depth'] <= Base_res),
        (df_results['Depth'] > Base_res)
        ]
    df_results['definition'] = np.select(conditions, ['Overburden','Reservoir','Underburden'])   # defining data points as either overburden, reservoir and underburden
    # Calculation of Uz (broken into smaller componants)
    Z = df_results['Z (m)']
    a = (Cm/2)*Res_thickness*Depletion*Biot
    b = (C*(Z-1))/pow(1+C*C*(Z-1)*(Z-1),(1/2))
    c = ((3-(4*nu))*C*(Z+1))/pow(1+C*C*(Z+1)*(Z+1),(1/2))
    d = (2*C*Z)/pow((1+C*C*(Z+1)*(Z+1)),(3/2))
    e_OB = 3-(4*nu)+1   # +1 used if overburden
    e_UB = 3-(4*nu)-1   # -1 used if underburden
    conditions = [
        (df_results['definition'] == 'Overburden'),
        (df_results['definition'] == 'Reservoir'),
        (df_results['definition'] == 'Underburden')
        ]
    Uz_OB = a*(b-c+d+e_OB)
    Uz_UB = a*(b-c+d+e_UB)
    df_results['Uz (m)'] = np.select(conditions, [Uz_OB,Uz_OB,Uz_UB])   # calculation of Uz
    df_results['Uz (cm)'] = df_results['Uz (m)'] * 100
    Uz_end = df_results['Uz (m)'].iloc[-1]    # Extracting the end Uz value
    df_results['Vertical displacement (m)'] = df_results['Uz (m)'] - Uz_end    # Calculation of vertical displacement
    df_results['Vertical displacement (cm)'] = df_results['Vertical displacement (m)']*100
    df_results
    
results(Water_depth,e,intv,Top_res,Base_res,Res_thickness,Depletion, Biot,Cm,C,nu)
```

I would expect the outcome to be:

```
Depth   Z (m)   definition  Uz (m)  Uz (cm) Vertical displacement (m)   Vertical displacement (cm)
0   127 0.000000    Overburden  0.023697    2.369732    0.021055    2.105454
1   227 0.057670    Overburden  0.024022    2.402241    0.021380    2.137963
2   327 0.115340    Overburden  0.024337    2.433735    0.021695    2.169456
3   427 0.173010    Overburden  0.024642    2.464211    0.021999    2.199932
4   527 0.230681    Overburden  0.024937    2.493682    0.022294    2.229404
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
74  7527    4.267589    Underburden 0.002725    0.272521    0.000082    0.008243
75  7627    4.325260    Underburden 0.002705    0.270523    0.000062    0.006245
76  7727    4.382930    Underburden 0.002685    0.268480    0.000042    0.004202
77  7827    4.440600    Underburden 0.002664    0.266397    0.000021    0.002119
78  7927    4.498270    Underburden 0.002643    0.264278    0.000000    0.000000
79 rows × 7 columns
```

However, the outputs from running:

```
results(Water_depth,e,intv,Top_res,Base_res,Res_thickness,Depletion, Biot,Cm,C,nu)
df_results
```

is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 33
     30     df_results
     32 results(Water_depth,e,intv,Top_res,Base_res,Res_thickness,Depletion, Biot,Cm,C,nu)
---> 33 df_results

NameError: name 'df_results' is not defined
```

Comment: You only create `df_results` in the local function namespace, not globally. Why don't you `return` it, and then set `df_results = results(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def results(Water_depth,e,intv,Top_res,Base_res,Res_thickness,Depletion, Biot,Cm,C,nu): 
    df_results = pd.DataFrame((np.arange(Water_depth,e,intv)), columns=['Depth'])   # Creating data frame for results
    df_results['Z (m)'] = ((df_results['Depth']) - Water_depth)/Top_res    # Creating normalised depth
    conditions = [
        (df_results['Depth'] < Top_res),
        (df_results['Depth'] >= Top_res) & (df_results['Depth'] <= Base_res),
        (df_results['Depth'] > Base_res)
        ]
    df_results['definition'] = np.select(conditions, ['Overburden','Reservoir','Underburden'])   # defining data points as either overburden, reservoir and underburden
    # Calculation of Uz (broken into smaller componants)
    Z = df_results['Z (m)']
    a = (Cm/2)*Res_thickness*Depletion*Biot
    b = (C*(Z-1))/pow(1+C*C*(Z-1)*(Z-1),(1/2))
    c = ((3-(4*nu))*C*(Z+1))/pow(1+C*C*(Z+1)*(Z+1),(1/2))
    d = (2*C*Z)/pow((1+C*C*(Z+1)*(Z+1)),(3/2))
    e_OB = 3-(4*nu)+1   # +1 used if overburden
    e_UB = 3-(4*nu)-1   # -1 used if underburden
    conditions = [
        (df_results['definition'] == 'Overburden'),
        (df_results['definition'] == 'Reservoir'),
        (df_results['definition'] == 'Underburden')
        ]
    Uz_OB = a*(b-c+d+e_OB)
    Uz_UB = a*(b-c+d+e_UB)
    df_results['Uz (m)'] = np.select(conditions, [Uz_OB,Uz_OB,Uz_UB])   # calculation of Uz
    df_results['Uz (cm)'] = df_results['Uz (m)'] * 100
    Uz_end = df_results['Uz (m)'].iloc[-1]    # Extracting the end Uz value
    df_results['Vertical displacement (m)'] = df_results['Uz (m)'] - Uz_end    # Calculation of vertical displacement
    df_results['Vertical displacement (cm)'] = df_results['Vertical displacement (m)']*100
    return df_results
    
df_results = results(Water_depth,e,intv,Top_res,Base_res,Res_thickness,Depletion, Biot,Cm,C,nu)
print(df_results)
```

You are never returning the value of df_results and never storing it, so it never exist

Simply return the value, and store it in a variable then
Check variable scope for more information